# Why does div not display css?

Tags: html, css

why does .header not show background color and height settings?

https://jsfiddle.net/f3puaeq6/1/

```
.header{
background-color: black;
height: 300px;

}
```

Comment: because your html is malformed: <div class="header"</div> should be <div class="header"></div>

Comment: Thats embarassing! :-) thank you for that catch @Christina it now correctly displays the height however the color doesn't show or it is hidden behind the body background image how do i fix this?

Comment: This issue happens if I view it in codepen.io but works in jsfiddle. Is there a reason for this that i'm not catching? there is a difference in the carousel as well where the carousel displays properly in codepen.io but not in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you haven't closed the tag   `<div class="header"</div>`, change it to:

```
 <div class="header></div>
```

Look carefully and try to debug your code. Install a good **IDE**

Comment: Thank you for catching my silly mistake @ zombieChowder. Do you happen to know why the display of this code changes between jsfiddle and codepen.io? :-)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "the display of this code changes". If you could provide me with both examples, I could probably tell you. Meanwhile if you answer helped you, feel free to accept it.

Comment: http://codepen.io/fjenpen/pen/pROPov & https://jsfiddle.net/f3puaeq6/1/

Comment: Some browsers and some code sharing places are more forgiving of lousy syntax and will auto close when they parse.

Comment: @Christina I've just started teaching myself code and appreciate your help with this question. May I ask is this lousy syntax? https://codepen.io/adethrax/pen/bNQyJP when I place this in to a jsfiddle it breaks. I can't see where there is bad syntax? https://jsfiddle.net/ubk50wtr/